# Pass a global variable to another view backbone

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-views

I have a view with a map rendered, and this view have a global variable `map`, and want pass this variable to another view to render makers in that map. It´s possible to do that?

first_view

```
ev.views.Home = Backbone.View.extend({
    map: 'null',
    initialize: function(){
        this.template = _.template(ev.templateLoader.get('home'));
        this.render();
    },

    initMap: function(){

        ...
    },

    render: function(){
                this.$el.html(this.template);
                this.initMap();
                return this;
    }   
});
```

second_view

```
ev.views.Lista = Backbone.View.extend({

initialize: function(){
    this.template = _.template(ev.templateLoader.get('lista_eventos'));
    this.render();
},

render: function(){
    var that = this;
    var imagens = new ev.models.ImagemCollection();
    imagens.fetch({
        success: function(){
            that.$el.html(that.template({imagens: imagens.models}));
            var marcadores = imagens.models;
            setTimeout(function() {
            _.each(marcadores, function(marcador){

                console.log("aquiiiiii");
                var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(marcador.get('latitude'),marcador.get('longitude'));
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: myLatlng,
                    map: this.map,
                });

            });
                }, 10000);
        }
    });

}

});
```

EDIT:

Merge the method `render` ev.views.Lista to the method `render` of ev.views.Home, like this:

```
ev.views.Home = Backbone.View.extend({
        map: 'null',
        initialize: function(){
            this.template = _.template(ev.templateLoader.get('home'));
            this.render();
        },

        initMap: function(){

            ...
        },

        render: function(){
        var that = this;
        var imagens = new ev.models.ImagemCollection();
        imagens.fetch({
        success: function(){
            that.$el.html(that.template({imagens: imagens.models}));
            that.initMap();
            var marcadores = imagens.models;
            setTimeout(function() {
            _.each(marcadores, function(marcador){
               var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(marcador.get('latitude'),marcador.get('longitude'));
                   var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                       position: myLatlng,
                       map: that.map,
                });

            });
            }, 10000);
            return that;
        }
    });

}


    });
```

Answer (score 1):

First, I don't understand what you mean by global. In your code there is no global variables I could see. I think you're misusing the term.

The design needs to be questioned. The responsibility of state might benefit being placed in a different context / hierarchy. Even so, I'll answer with the simplest answer I could think of at the moment. Pass the view that manages the map to the `initialize` method of the second view and save an instance reference.

Change your `ev.views.Lista.initialize()` method to accept an argument. Then save the reference. Finally reference the mapView from your render function.

```
ev.views.Lista = Backbone.View.extend({
  initialize: function(mapView) {
    this.mapView = mapView;
    this.render();
  },

  render: function() {
    this.mapView.map; // Your map object you want.
  }
});

var myMapView   = new ev.views.Home();
var myListaView = new ev.views.Lista(myListaView);
```

## Warning!

By doing this you are tightly coupling your views to each other. This is a very bad code smell and will cause heartache in the future when you come back and attempt to maintain or scale your code. Try to avoid such things and never look to the short term solutions. As stated above the better answer is to redesign the responsibility to other object. Perhaps have a MapManager who manages maps and can be queried for a reference to the map object of interest.

```
ev.MapManager = {
  maps: {},
  add: function(name, map) {
    this.maps[name] = map;
  },
  remove: function(name) {
    this.maps[name] = null;
  },
  get: function(name) {
    return this.maps[name];
  }
};
```

Comment: With your explanation I realize that the way I'm doing this it's not correct. So I merge the method `render` of `ev.views.Lista` to the method `render` of `ev.views.Home` and as result I have one view. The changes are edited above.